# Excluding max length, what limitations does a string in java have?

Tags: java, string

Excluding max length, what limitations does a string in java have?

Are there things I cant put in one? Characters they wont accept?

Any would be a great help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "string"? Do yo mean an object of class `String`, or do you mean "text input data"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your usage scenario: Java uses UTF-16 for String representation meaning that Strings in Java might use more Memory than UTF-8/ASCII/ISO-XXXXX.

Comment: +1: Java 6 update 21+ has `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` on by default.  This uses `byte[]` instead of `char[]` for long lived Strings where possible.

Answer (score 3):

Java strings can contain any data you like, they're binary strings. However, certain functions may not work with malformed strings (e.g. containing \x00), depending on your specified character encoding. You can (probably) rely on the standard methods to work, but keep in mind that by inserting "bad" characters you're abusing the type, and you may break other people's code.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure, but maybe there is a limit on the length of the string Integer.MAX_VALUE

```
public final class String
  111     implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence
  112 {
  113     /** The value is used for character storage. */
  114     private final char value[];
```

[String.java](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7/jdk/file/9b8c96f96a0f/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java)

Comment: The question specified _excluding max length_.